# A combination of an itemized list and a table

Tags: tables, spacing, itemize

Consider the following document with an itemized list with two words per item:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item arbitrary, archipelago
\item bug, bit
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

This prints as follows:

[image: An itemized list with two words on each row]

I would like the second word on every item row to be a fixed distance apart, so that the outcome will look like this:

[image: The words on each row are spaced out in a synchronized manner]

I can accomplish this effect with `\hspace`:

```
\item arbitrary,\hspace{4.2cm}archipelago
\item bug,\hspace{5cm}bit
```

but this is too much work and unwieldy, as the spaces need to be tailored for every combination of words.

I can use a table with `textbullet`:

```
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hskip 4cm}l}
 \textbullet\ arbitrary, & archipelago \\
 \textbullet\ bug, & bit \\
\end{tabular}
```

but the formatting is not the same as a list:

[image: Table vs. list]

Note the distance of the bullet points from the left margin, the distance between the bullet points and the beginning of the text, and the distance between the rows.

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{ @{} l@{\hskip 4cm}l}
 \textbullet\ arbitrary, & archipelago \\
 \textbullet\ bug, & bit \\
\end{tabular}` ?

Comment: @Zarko: This solution does not quite look like an itemized list. See the last paragraph in the post.

Comment: than increase space after `\textbulet` or nest `itemize` in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listliketab}
\begin{document}

A tabular

\storestyleof{itemize}
\begin{listliketab}
\begin{tabular}{Lll}
\textbullet& arbitrary, & archipelago \\
\textbullet& bug,       & bit \\
\end{tabular}
\end{listliketab}

A list

\begin{itemize}
\item arbitrary
\item bug
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]